# Excon::Error::Socket: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints, fog

I'm attempting to use fog-google to upload images to my google cloud storage. 
My code looks like this:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  storage: :fog,
  fog_host: "https://#{ENV.fetch('GOOGLE_STORAGE_BUCKET')}.storage.googleapis.com",
  fog_credentials: {
      google_storage_access_key_id: ENV.fetch('GOOGLE_STORAGE_ID'),
      google_storage_secret_access_key: ENV.fetch('GOOGLE_STORAGE_SECRET'),
      provider: 'Google' },
  fog_directory: ENV.fetch('GOOGLE_STORAGE_BUCKET') }
```

However, I always get this error:
`Excon::Error::Socket: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)`

Seems like the connection is not established successfully.

Here is the error log:

```
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/excon-0.59.0/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb:117:in `connect_nonblock'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/excon-0.59.0/lib/excon/ssl_socket.rb:117:in `initialize'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/excon-0.59.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:404:in `new'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/excon-0.59.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:404:in `socket'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/excon-0.59.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:101:in `request_call'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/excon-0.59.0/lib/excon/middlewares/mock.rb:48:in `request_call'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/excon-0.59.0/lib/excon/middlewares/instrumentor.rb:26:in `request_call'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/excon-0.59.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:16:in `request_call'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/excon-0.59.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:16:in `request_call'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/excon-0.59.0/lib/excon/middlewares/base.rb:16:in `request_call'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/excon-0.59.0/lib/excon/connection.rb:250:in `request'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fog-core-1.45.0/lib/fog/core/connection.rb:81:in `request'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fog-xml-0.1.3/lib/fog/xml/connection.rb:9:in `request'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fog-google-0.6.0/lib/fog/storage/google_xml/real.rb:103:in `request'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fog-google-0.6.0/lib/fog/storage/google_xml/requests/head_object.rb:36:in `head_object'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/fog-google-0.6.0/lib/fog/storage/google_xml/models/files.rb:81:in `head'
C:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/paperclip-5.1.0/lib/paperclip/storage/fog.rb:65:in `exists?'
```

Comment: Is it possible you are behind a proxy? In many cases the proxy will interfere with the handshake which can lead to this sort of problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when I switch from windows to Linux.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are trying to reach a url https and is failing to verify ssl in your case.

Try adding    `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`

*Edit - For Your concern about **Man In The Middle Attack***

Also You can verify your application by adding an ssl certificate with the following steps

- Download https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem into a path_to_file\cacert.pem. Make sure you save it as a .pem file, rather than a text file.
- Set Environment Variable: `SSL_CERT_FILE = path_to_file\cacert.pem`
- Restart all your ruby / rails applications and the retry accessing it now.

Comment: I dont think this is a good idea. I do want to prevent man in the middle attack.

Comment: then you should try getting your application ssl verified

Comment: my application already uses a pem file that is provided by excon

Comment: also, I attempted to set verify_peer in debug mode, same error

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows Linux subsystem. Disabling IPV6 worked (For the hyper-V) for me.